# help with PHP and interbase

Tags: php, interbase

im trying to create a PHP web application to connec to an interbase database. Iv installed xampp for the PHP and Apache. I then installed Firebird SQL 2.5 to get the required DLL's. however iv noticed that in the php\ext folder there doesnt seem to be a php_interbase.dll which from what iv read is needed. can some one please direct me in the right direction where I can get the needed DLL or even how i should ste up my machine in order for me to be able to connect to interbase.

when i try to connect to the database i get the following error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phase\includes\config.php on line 11**

Answer (score 2):

1. php_interbase.dll   Requires: gds32.dll (bundled)
2. http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq191/
3. http://www.alberton.info/firebird_php_windows.html

Comment: im following the tutorial (3) but i still cant get it to work. where might i get the gds32.dll(bundled) from ?

Comment: I think this is not what you should worry about because one of the steps is
>>Copy C:\firebird\bin\fbclient.dll to your C:\windows\system32 directory and rename the file to gds32.dll

Comment: iv followed the tutorial step by step, i forgot to mention that i am using a 64bit system, can this have anything to do with it ? im also trying to run the script on the firebird faq page but i cant connect to my database.

Comment: hm don't know about 64bit system.. where did you get php_interbase.dll  ?

Comment: i just googled it and downloaded the first one, this might be whats causing the error. where can i get the correct php_interbase.dll from ?

Comment: I figured out that a lot of people have problems with windows7 and php/interbase but still no real answers ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. If your client is 64-bit, it's called ibclient64.dll, not gds32.dll

Answer (score 0):

for windows64

copy file C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_*_*\WOW64\fbclient.dll

to :C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fbclient.dll